# How to write multiple input bindings of same function definition name?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I want to use the same consumer function definition for multiple bindings with different index.
In the below `yml`, it is only working with `testConsumer-in-0` it is not listening to the destination of `testConsumer-in-1 binding`. all binder binder related configurations are correct.

```
public Consumer<Message<String>> testConsumer() {
        return incomingMessage -> {
            log.debug("received from kafka-binder");
       };
}


yml :-

spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: testConsumer
    stream:
      bindings:
        testConsumer-in-1:
          destination: test-request-a1
          binder: kafka1
          group: test-consumer-group-a1
        testConsumer-in-0:
          destination: test-request-a2
          binder: kafka2
          group: test-consumer-group-a2
```

Comment: function name is testConsumer()

Answer (score 0):

But there is only one input argument for that `Consumer` signature. Therefore it is correct that it sees only that `testConsumer-in-0`. What you are trying to do is contradicting with a purpose of Spring Cloud Stream. If you are going to consume from different topic and looks like even from different Kafka clusters, then you need to consider to start separate instances of your application. And both of then have to use the same binding point - `testConsumer-in-0`.

See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_functional_binding_names

Comment: is there any alternative that i can do ? i want my consumer function can be used by multiple kafka clusters, so  later if i want to connect another kafka cluster there would be no code change.

Comment: Well, that is correct: no changes to the code. When you got a new cluster, you just spawn new instance of this application with respective binding configuration.